# React navigation between pages

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm getting a component exception error. Couldn't find a 'component', getComponent or 'children' prop for the screen 'HomePage.'

And I looked through some google search and the only thing I was able to find was that I need to use `export default X` and `import X from 'path'` together and regular `export` with `import { X } from 'path'`.

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrongly here. Can someone help?

This is my HomePage.jsx:

```
const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Page</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

and this is my App.jsx:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import HomePage from './src/pages/HomePage';
import TablePage from './src/pages/TablePage';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.jsx to start working on your app!</Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
      <TabNavBar />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNavBar() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" compotent={HomePage} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Table" compotent={TablePage} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: fix `compotent` to `component` in your tab declaration. as the error mentioned, your tab declarations failed to find a corresponding component to render for your routes as you have a typo in your route declarations.

Comment: oh. my. actual. god. thank you so much!! another day wondering why I chose this path :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" compotent={HomePage} />
```

with

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomePage} />
```

and same for "`Table`".